# AWS S3 bucket is not remounting after restarting EC2 Instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I mounted my S3 bucket to my EC2 Instance using **S3fs**, and I was able to read, write to my S3 bucket. But after restarting my EC2 Instance, S3 bucket is automatically unmounted.
I found that to make it persistent and automatically mount for every reboot we need to add below entries to /etc/rc.local

`/usr/bin/s3fs myS3bucket -o use_cache=/tmp -o allow_other -o multireq_max=5 /myS3bucket`

But still It is not mounting on reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you went through the official [documentation](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse)?

> You can also mount on boot by entering the following line to /etc/fstab:
>
> s3fs#mybucket /path/to/mountpoint fuse _netdev,allow_other 0 0
>
> or
>
> (…)
>
> Note2: You may also need to make sure netfs service is start on boot

A network mount requires a network access in the first place.

Comment: Actually I did change it in /etc/fstab but was not working. Now with your syntax its working. Thanks :)

Comment: Glad I helped. Consider marking this as the answer then. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was  able  to  make it work  by running it as  `systemd` service.

- Create Service File - `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mybucket-mount.service`

  ```
  [Unit]
  Description = Mount S3 Bucket my-bucket
  Wants=network-online.target
  After=network.target network-online.target

  [Service]
  Type=oneshot
  RemainAfterExit=yes
  ExecStart = /usr/bin/s3fs my-bucket /MyBucketMount/ -o uid=500,gid=501,iam_role=MyRole,use_cache=/tmp,endpoint=ap-south-1,url=https://s3.amazonaws.com
  ExecStop=/bin/umount /MyBucketMount/

  [Install]
  WantedBy = multi-user.target
  ```
- Create Link

  ```
  ln  -sf /usr/lib/systemd/system/mybucket-mount.service /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mybucket-mount.service
  ```
- Enable Service

  ```
  systemctl enable mybucket-mount.service
  ```
- Start Service

  ```
  systemctl start mybucket-mount.service
  ```